# How does one apply an attribute to an attribute?

Tags: c#

This https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx says

"A target element can be an assembly, class, constructor, delegate, enum,    event, field, interface, method, portable executable file module, parameter, property, return value, struct, **or another attribute.**"

I know you can apply an attribute to a ValidationAttribute class like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)] 
public class ValidInteger : ValidationAttribute
```

Is that what they mean? Or can you actually apply an attribute to an attribute? If so, how?

I know "Attribute" isn't listed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets(v=vs.110).aspx, but if you selected "All" could you do it?

Answer (score 0):

No an attribute cannot be applied to an attribute directly. If you write a custom attribute and inherit other in the same, might be a process you would have implemented what you have asked for. With `all` they mean:

- Assembly
- Class
- Constructor
- Delegate
- Enum
- Event
- Field
- Interface
- Method
- Module (this refers to a .NET executable file, not a VB module)
- Parameter
- Property
- ReturnValue
- Struct